# ActionScript 2 loadClip depth

Tags: image, actionscript, actionscript-2

When I use:

```
loader = new MovieClipLoader();
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("level1",getNextHighestDepth());
_root.level1.createEmptyMovieClip("image",getNextHighestDepth());
loader.loadClip("http://someimage.jpg",_root.level1.image);
```

...it works and the image shows up.
But when I use:

```
loader = new MovieClipLoader();
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("level1",getNextHighestDepth());
_root.level1.createEmptyMovieClip("level2",getNextHighestDepth());
_root.level1.level2.createEmptyMovieClip("image",getNextHighestDepth());
loader.loadClip("http://someimage.jpg",_root.level1.level2.image);
```

...the image doesn't show up. Can anyone tell me why? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

the depth you are supplying is going to be '1'. is that what you are expecting?

each movie clip has it's own set of depths, so the nextHighestDepth() of the newly create 'image' mc, will be 1. it should not prevent loading the image though.

Answer (score 0):

As gthmb says, you should call getNextHighestDepth() on the same MovieClip as you do the createEmptyMovieClip() on. So your code example should be more like:

```
loader = new MovieClipLoader();
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("level1",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
_root.level1.createEmptyMovieClip("level2",_root.level1.getNextHighestDepth());
_root.level1.level2.createEmptyMovieClip("image",_root.level1.level2.getNextHighestDepth());
loader.loadClip("http://someimage.jpg",_root.level1.level2.image);
```

Also, I would recommend storing references to the created MovieClips, so you won't have to use the full path in each occurrence in the code, something in the lines of this:

```
loader = new MovieClipLoader();
var level1:MovieClip = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("level1",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
var level2:MovieClip = level1.createEmptyMovieClip("level2",level1.getNextHighestDepth());
var image:MovieClip = level2.createEmptyMovieClip("image",level2.getNextHighestDepth());
loader.loadClip("http://someimage.jpg",image);
```